# Why i got 11 10 10 from given range 10 to 1?

Tags: c

I want to print numbers from left to right. If the left number is larger than the right, it will print numbers from smallest to largest. If the right number is larger than the left, it will print number from largest to smallest. And if the given numbers are equal, it will print just that number.

Expected behavior:

```
enter 2 integers : 4 10
4 5 6 7 8 9 10

enter 2 integers: 10 4
10 9 8 7 6 5 4

enter 2 integers: 4 4 
4

enter 2 integers: 4 3
4 3
```

This is my code:

```c
int main() {
    int i, n1, n2;
    printf("Enter range (n1, n2 ) : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    i = n1;
    while (i <= n2) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        i++;
    }
    while (i >= n2) {
        printf("%d ", i);
        i--;
        if (i == n2) {
            printf("%d", i);
        }
    }
}
```

When I type input like 1 and 10, it prints output like this: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 10`.

But if I type input like 10 and 1, it prints output like this: `10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 11`.

If I type equal numbers, it prints so many numbers.

How can I fix this? I've been trying many ways, thanks for help.

Comment: Sit down with pen and paper and think about the logic of the whole assignment and what you're supposed to do. Write stuff down, try different things on paper. When you have something on paper that seems to work, implement it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. -- Look for some coding style and stick to it, most importantly, use a consistent indentation. I have already formatted your source code. -- Among the now obvious algorithmic error in your code, do what @Someprogrammerdude recommends. You should also learn [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Try doing it without the variable `i` ... printing and changing `n1` directly

Comment: "If the left number is larger than the right, it will print numbers from smallest to largest. If the right number is larger than the left, it will print number from largest to smallest." does not match shown expected behaviour. It is reverse.

Answer (score 0):

You unconditionally execute both loops and get output from both, the output you want and an edge case from the other loop.

Use an if to decide between the two loops and only exectute one of them.

That way you avoid that after the first loop the condition of the second one is true once. Note that after `while (i <= n2) i++;` it is sure that `i>n2`, e.g. `i==n2+1`. And in the second loop, after the first `i--;`, it is true that `i==n2`.

Note that the "11" in the second shown output is not an eleven, it is two "1"s, missing a blank. Coming each from one `printf()` inside the second loop.

Here is code to illustrate the problem (not to fix it):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n1, n2;
    printf("Enter range (n1, n2 ) : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    i = n1;
    while (i <= n2) {
        printf("1st:%d\n", i);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n1 done\n");
    while (i >= n2) {
        printf("2nd:%d\n", i);
        i--;
        if (i == n2) {
            printf("if:%d\n", i);
        }
    }
}
```

output for "1 10":

```
Enter range (n1, n2 ) : 1st:1
1st:2
1st:3
1st:4
1st:5
1st:6
1st:7
1st:8
1st:9
1st:10

1 done
2nd:11
if:10
2nd:10
```

output for "10 1":

```
Enter range (n1, n2 ) : 
1 done
2nd:10
2nd:9
2nd:8
2nd:7
2nd:6
2nd:5
2nd:4
2nd:3
2nd:2
if:1
2nd:1
```

Code to fix, adding an if and deleting a different if,
still with some visualisation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n1, n2;
    printf("Enter range (n1, n2 ) : ");
    scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
    i = n1;
    if(n1 < n2)
    {
        while (i <= n2) {
            printf("1st:%d\n", i);
            i++;
        }
    } else
    {
        while (i >= n2) {
            printf("2nd:%d\n", i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while` also behaves like `if`: no need to decide between the two loops. See https://ideone.com/bGxtBa :-)

Comment: @pmg But the variable in the condition is changed to match the condition of the second loop. Two contrary ifs both fire if in between you change the checked variable suitably. The code in your link relevantly differs in `<` not being `<=`.

Comment: @pmg I added code and output to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

You can print numbers in a given range using a single while loop and flag.

**flag variable:** flag to determine you have to increment or
decrement     (true means decrement)

```
 #include<stdio.h>
  int main() {
            int n1, n2;
            bool flag=false; 
            printf("Enter range (n1, n2 ) : ");
            scanf("%d %d", &n1, &n2);
           if(n1>n2)
             flag=true;
            else
             flag=false; 
            while(n1!=n2)
            {
            printf("%d ", n1);
            if(flag)
             n--;
            else
             n++;
            }
           printf("%d", n1);
        }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. (downvote not by me by the way)

Comment: Suggestion: avoid `?:` use `int direction = 2*(n1<n2) - 1;` and `n1 += direction;` inside the loop. Forked my previous code to https://ideone.com/KCDnYt

Comment: ... or explain the advantages of `?:` which outweigh the disadvantages of using expressions with side effects as conditional statements, which at least in my opinion decreases readability.